# Conditions on inequalities $a>b$ and $b<c$ to deduce $a<c.$

Tags: inequality

If $a>b$ and $b<c$, and $a$ and $c$ are positive, under what conditions is $a<c$? I am just curious to know. I know that the following are true $\frac ab>1$, $\frac bc<1$, and $\frac ac<1$. Any ideas on what next?

Comment: It is not possible to deduce $a<c$ there is too little information.

Comment: $a>b$ does not imply $a/b > 1$. Take $a=1$ and $b=-1$, for instance

Comment: $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive

Comment: I don't know if this is also the case for you, but I have seen people getting very confused in situations involving inequalities because the did not realize a simple truth: **$b < c$  means exactly the same as $c > b$.**

Comment: So we can rewrite your conditions as $a > b$ and $c > b$ or put in words 'both $a$ and $c$ are bigger than $b$. The information we have about $a$ is exactly the same as the information we have about $c$ and hence this information is not enough to tell the two apart or say which one is bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for.

$$\begin{cases} a>b \\ b<c \\ a=\min \left\{a,c\right\} \\ a≠c \end{cases} \Longrightarrow a<c$$

Comment: Is it mathematically correct to make the assumption to be able to prove a convergence result that is valid under the deduction of $a<c$? Some people are saying nothing can be said about $a$ and $c$. $$\begin{cases} a>b \\ b<c \\ a=\min \left\{a,c\right\} \\ a≠c \end{cases} \Longrightarrow a<c$$. This condition you stated is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not say anything about $a$ and $c$. Try the following examples:

$$b=1,a=3,c=2\Rightarrow a>c$$

$$b=1,a=2,c=3\Rightarrow a<c$$

$$b=1,a=2,c=2\Rightarrow a=c$$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe transcribing in everyday life situation would help.

If a child $\ b\ $ is smaller than his mother $\ a\ $ (i.e $a>b$) and his father $\ c\ $ (i.e $b<c$)

Then how can you deduce the mother is smaller than the father ($a<b$) ?

There is not enough information to know. What could work would be to know "how much smaller is the child compared to his parents", i.e. knowing the value of the fractions $\frac ba$ and $\frac bc$ we can calculate $\frac ac$ and compare it to $1$.

Comment: Do you agree that the following is true? $$\begin{cases} a>b \\ b<c \\ a=\min \left\{a,c\right\} \\ a≠c \end{cases} \Longrightarrow a<c$$.

Comment: It is true. $a=\min(a,c)\implies a\le c$ by itself. So if you suppose $a\neq c$ also then $a<c$ is true. You do not need the two other conditions.